# Workflow Triggrs at Every Change

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Scenario: I have created separate workflows for one list.  The first workflow triggers only at the creations of an item.  I changed the workflow settings to "start at creation".  For the second workflow I wanted to trigger an email to be sent with an "current item" is not empty.

```
If CurrentItem:NFL is not empty
   Send Email 
Stop Workflow
```

I changed the workflow settings to trigger when an item is changed . The problem is this workflow keeps trigger when any item is changed and current item is empty.  Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: An on change workflow will fire everytime the item is changed, that's what it does. So long as the NFL field has a value, it will always send out the email.

Comment: @EricAlexander Thank you but I only want it to trigger once.  Once the item is changed and NFL is selected I want the email to be sent.  But right now every time the item is changed it keeps triggering the email.  I only want it to send one time once the NFL item is not empty.  After that I do not want the email to be sent out again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow is functioning as designed in this case. Every time the list item is edited and the NFL field is not blank, it sends the email. To curb this, you'll need to create an additional tracking column in your list, either a boolean or choice. Then you'd adjust the workflow like so:

```
If CurrentItem:NFL is not empty
 and if CurrentItem: TrackingColumn is equal to No
   Send Email 
   Set field in CurrentItem (setting Tracking column to Yes)
Stop Workflow
```

This will prevent it from sending emails every time the item is edited.